# Почему к плагину bootstrap form helper language picker нельзя применить никаких скриптов?

Tags: javascript, html5, bootstrap

Я использую плагин Bootstrap Form Helpers Languages на своем сайте, и проблема в том, что он с помощью JS генерирует практически всю структуру, и нет возможности ничего изменить или добавить (за исключением языков). Основная проблема в том, что он генерирует список языков с тегом а, но при нажатии на них ничего не происходит. Я пробовал додать к ним href атрибуты:

```
$("ul[role='option'] > li > a[data-option='pl_PL']").prop("href", "/index.php?lang=pl_PL");
$("ul[role='option'] > li > a[data-option='en_US']").prop("href", "/index.php?lang=en_US");
```

Так же пробовал trigger() и click(...).
В firebug видно что они добавились, но никаких действии не происходит. Я просмотрел весь код плагина, но не нашел ничего, что может блокировать их роботу.
Адрес сайта: [здесь](http://vasyldemianiuk.com) ( немного недокуренный, проблемы с ssl, но на localhost та же проблема). 
Весь код сайта: https://github.com/WELES777/PORTFOLIO.git

Comment: нужен не _Весь код сайта_, а [mcve] - то есть **минимальный** код, позволяющий воспроизвести ошибку. Кроме того, он должен быть добавлен непосредственно в вопрос, ссылки могут быть дополнением